# Android Keyboard appear after Tabbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have four tabs in my home screen and one of them takes user input,
I have a two problem one is when open tab activity then android keyboard automatically open
and another problem is keyboard coming after tabbar.

I already added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my menifetch file

I Share My code

My createchallan.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="Search" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ems="5" >

    <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</EditText>


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/review"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search"
    android:text="Review Item" />



<RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/review"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="#E5E4E2"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Item Code"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
   />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtItemcode"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="Item" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dip"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="Quantity" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/listlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_below="@+id/header"
      android:layout_above="@+id/lastbutton">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/createlist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#adb8c2"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" 

   >

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>



 <RelativeLayout 
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

     android:id="@+id/lastbutton"

    android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

     android:orientation="horizontal" >


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/createcancel"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/createsavedraft"
          android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="  Cancel  " />


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/createsavedraft"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/creatapprove"
          android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="  Save Draft  " />



     <Button
        android:id="@+id/creatapprove"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="  Approve  " />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

my custom xml create_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 


 android:orientation="horizontal" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemcode"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="323232"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
     android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItem"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="9dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtItemcode"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtItemcode"
    android:text="5456455565456"
     android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editcreateQuantity"
     android:layout_width="70dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
     android:ems="10"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtItemcode"
android:focusable="true"
     android:singleLine="true" >


</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code

```
public class CreateChallan extends Activity {


 ListView lstCreate;

 String[] strmainItemCode;
 String[] strItem;
 String[] strQuantity;
 Context context=this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createchallan);
    lstCreate= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.createlist);
    lstCreate.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    strmainItemCode= new String[]{"55555551","255555","355555","455555","555555"};

    strItem =new String[]{"A","B","C","D","F"};

    strQuantity =new String[]{"100","200","30","400","500"};

    CreateAdapter adapter= new CreateAdapter(this, strmainItemCode, strItem, strQuantity);

    lstCreate.setAdapter(adapter);

    lstCreate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position1, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(context, "Position", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}







// Create List Adapter

class CreateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
 {
    TextView txtItecode, txtItem;
    EditText editQuantity;
    String[] strItecode;
    String[] strItem;
    String[] strQuantity;
    Context context;

    CreateAdapter(Context context, String[] strItemcode, String[] strItem, String[] strQauntity)
    {
            super(context,R.layout.create_list_item,R.id.txtItemcode,strItemcode);
        this.context= context;
        this.strItecode= strItemcode;
        this.strItem= strItem;
        this.strQuantity= strQauntity;
    }
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View row;
         row=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_list_item, parent,false);

         txtItecode= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtItemcode);
         txtItem =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
         editQuantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editcreateQuantity);
         editQuantity.setSelected(false);
         txtItecode.setText(strItecode[position]);
         txtItem.setText(strItem[position]);
        editQuantity.setText(strQuantity[position]);

         txtItecode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

         return row;


     }
 }


  }
```

Comment: Are you using TabHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code on you manifest in TabHostActivity or tab parent activity..

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Thank u very much U save my lots of time

Answer (score 1):

Hi try below code on you manifest for activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

hope this will work,Thanks