# problems with focus and Softkeyboard of EdiTtext in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have two ListViews

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/containerLv"
android:background="@drawable/modify_task_master_fragment_style"
android:paddingBottom="6dp"
android:layout_margin="6dp">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:id="@+id/topListView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topListView"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/divid"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:id="@+id/scrollListView"/>
```

I put dynamically EditText into ListView
and when i start typing focus is lost.
I read about this problem and added to my activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

This solution helped, but another problem occurred  - while creating new items in Listview the SoftKeyboard is overlapping my editText. so i cant see what i'm typing.

There is no such problem without SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741007/android-keyboard-appear-after-tabbar/22741462#22741462

Answer (score 0):

Include in your manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Also, I recomended you that your root layout be a RelativeLayout.

Hope it helps you :)